# How to prove that every left ideal is a principal left ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

The ring we are considering is $R=C(x)[\partial]$, consisting of expressions like $A = \sum_i^n a_i(x)∂^i$, where $a_i(x) \in C(x)$, which is defined as the set of fractions of polynomials over the complex plane. The two operations on this ring are defined as $\sum_i^n a_i(x)∂^i + \sum_i^m b_i(x)∂^i := \sum_i^n(a_i(x) + b_i(x))∂^i$ for $n>m$ and $A\cdot B := \sum_i^na_i(x)\partial^ib_i(x)\partial^i$. Furthermore, $∂a(x) := a(x)∂ + a′(x)$, the prime denoting the derivative with respect to x. How can I prove that every left ideal in $R$ is a principal left ideal?

Comment: You working on the same assignment as [MisterMath](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718041/1108193)?

Comment: This is just a (worse written) duplicate Lemmon found.  For this reason, I've voted to close until improvements are made.